# Sort Mapreduce dataset

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, dataset

I'm trying to run the following project to sort a dataset.

But, when I execute the command: `Hadoop jar xx.jar /inputdir /output dir`, I get following error on the terminal:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set.
```

In the README file of project it is mentioned:

```
hadoop jar mrss-0.1.jar demo.SsJob -Dmapred.input.dir=data-stock -Dmapred.output.dir=result-stock
```

Here is link to the project:

https://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/secondary-sorting-aka-sorting-values-in-hadoops-mapreduce-programming-paradigm/#comment-2342

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parameters for the Input format to read from input path and Outputformat to write to output paths.
Here is an example on how to submit a job:

```
 // Create a new Job
 Job job = Job.getInstance();
 job.setJarByClass(MyJob.class);

 // Specify various job-specific parameters     
 job.setJobName("myjob");

 job.setInputPath(new Path("in"));
 job.setOutputPath(new Path("out"));

 job.setMapperClass(MyJob.MyMapper.class);
 job.setReducerClass(MyJob.MyReducer.class);

 // Submit the job, then poll for progress until the job is complete
 job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

or you can pass this when you execute the jar by passing parameters at command line using -D option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how to pass parametre using -D i tried now hadoop jar xx.jar packagenaame.class -D /inputpaath -D /outputpaath still dont work

Comment: I tried to add to run
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(jobConf,args[0]);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jobConf,arg[1]);
you mean jobConf is the same job here?
Job job = new Job(conf, "secondary sort"); ?

Comment: Refer to this Driver code. Might be helpfull https://github.com/VenkataKarthikP/Hadoop/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudwick/hadoop/wordcount/Driver.java

Comment: Here is my pseudocode but still don't work when i compiled only read hadoop jar xxx.jar /outputfile (dont read input path) and i get error
 Configuration conf = getConf();
  Job job = new Job(conf, "sort");
  FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
  Path output = new Path(args[1]);
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);
  job.setJarByClass(SsJob.class);
  job.setPartitionerClass(Natu.class);
job.waitForCompletion(true);
  return 0
I tried this but setinputpath dont regonize it
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(jobConf,args[0])
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jobConf,arg[1])

Comment: You should add this code as updates to your post. What error did you get when add FileInputFormat and FileOutputFormat?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is awkward... but u need to provide a space after -D. I.e "-Dmapred.output.dir" should be given as    "-D mapred.output.dir".

This happens because the -D configuration passing doesn't work with Hadoop as with a normal jvm configuration.

There is more detail regarding this in the hadoop definitive guide.

But to your problem? The space is the solution.

Comment: No even with space -D /input output still doesnt work but thank you anyway

Comment: -D and then the propertyName and then the value
example *-D mapred.input.dir="/input" -D mapred.output.dir="/output"*

Comment: hadoop jar mr.jar demo.SsJob -D mapred.input.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/input/ -D mapred.output.dir=/outxzz/
 Alwaays output directory not set